# How to delete/truncate tables from Hadoop-Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Please tell me how to delete table from hive and also tell from where i can get more information about hive queries.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [drop](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterDatabase) command to delete meta data and actual data from HDFS.

And just to delete data and keep the table structure, use truncate command.

For further help regarding hive ql, check [language manual of hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL).

Comment: Hive version 0.11 will support `TRUNCATE`. The documentation link provided in this answer is also out of date. Use [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL).

Answer (score 12):

To Truncate:

```
hive -e "TRUNCATE TABLE IF EXISTS $tablename"
```

To Drop:

```
hive -e "Drop TABLE IF EXISTS $tablename"
```

Comment: truncate table doesn't support 'if exists'  clause

Answer (score 6):

Use the following to delete all the tables in a linux environment.

```
hive -e 'show tables' | xargs -I '{}' hive -e 'drop table {}'
```