# How to delete rows in hive hadoop database

Tags: hadoop, hive, delete-row

I'm a newbie with hadoop & hive. I want to delete certain rows in my database - which is on hive-hadoop. I know its not supported out of the box, and that hadoop is a read only file system. I'm curious about what are the best approaches for accomplishing this. If anyone has done this before, can they share their learnings/procedures?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete and update a record in Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810537/how-to-delete-and-update-a-record-in-hive)

Comment: You should probably check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810537/how-to-delete-and-update-a-record-in-hive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to partition your data such that the rows you want to drop are in a partition unto themselves.  You can then drop the partition without impacting the rest of your table.  This is a fairly sustainable model, even if your dataset grows quite large.

Answer (score 13):

In Big Data there really aren't deletes.  That said, you can overwrite your table or partition if it isn't too big, or isolate your deletes to a particular partition like JamCon suggests.

For datasets which are not too huge, you can do something like

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mytable
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE ID NOT IN ( 'delete1', 'delete2', 'delete3');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mytable  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=0;
```

The above query first deletes the data files, as `OVERWRITE` option is specified in the query. Next it will execute `SELECT` to read the records from the table, as condition fails, `SELECT` query will get zero records and insert zero records into the table.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could insert the rest of of rows (i.e., those you want to keep) into another table and then drop the old table.