# Deleting rows from Hive external table

Tags: csv, hive

I have a Hive external table created from a list of CSV files.

If I perform a Hive delete on a table row (or a number of rows), will the corresponding CSV record/s will be deleted as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know you can't quite delete a row in Hive -- Hive's not a database, it's a scripting language for Map Reduce. However you could do something like

```
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO TABLE mytable
SELECT * from mytable 
where rowid <> 1;
```

In which case yes, the CSV will be updated. Also see the answers to this question
[How to delete and update a record in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810537/how-to-delete-and-update-a-record-in-hive)

Comment: `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mytable
SELECT * from mytable 
where rowid <> 1;` worked for me.

Comment: This solution does not work for partitioned external tables.