# Apache Hive not able to delete rows from table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using Apache Hive latest available version viz. apache-hive-1.2.1.
It is said that Apache Hive now supports Update, Delete statements.

But I am not able to delete rows. Behavior is as follows.

```
hive> delete employee;
Usage: delete [FILE|JAR|ARCHIVE] <value> [<value>]*
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: null

hive> delete * from employee;
Usage: delete [FILE|JAR|ARCHIVE] <value> [<value>]*
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: null

hive> delete from employee where 1=2;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete     using transaction manager that does not support these operations.
```

EDIT : Discussion at [How to delete and update a record in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810537/how-to-delete-and-update-a-record-in-hive)  mentions that new version of Hive supports these operations. But my experience here is different. 
So this question is specific to new version and how to enable these operations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete and update a record in Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810537/how-to-delete-and-update-a-record-in-hive)

Comment: @Avinash I had referred that thread. Accepted answer refers to older version where DELETE/UPDATE were not available. Other answer which mentions new version. My question is specific to new version and if there are any additional settings needed.

Comment: Pl. check this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Delete Deletes can only be performed on tables that support ACID. Check if the empolyees table satisfies this criteria

Comment: Your table properties should include transactional=true. i.e TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true")