# Cannot update table in hive.

Tags: linux, hive, cloudera

When I try to update or delete in the hive table, I get the error

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or
>   delete using transaction manager that does not support these
>   operations.

I have created a table as

```
create table testTableNew(id int ,name string ) clustered by (id) into
2 buckets stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');
```

I am using cloudera. Am I missing something? I am new to hive and need some help for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete and update a record in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810537/how-to-delete-and-update-a-record-in-hive)

Comment: you should add the code that you are using for update/delete

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't support Update/Delete operations.