# How to truncate a partitioned external table in hive?

Tags: hive, truncate, external-tables, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I'm planning to truncate the hive external table which has one partition. So, I have used the following command to truncate the table :

```
 hive> truncate table abc;
```

But, it is throwing me an error stating : **Cannot truncate non-managed table abc.**

Can anyone please suggest me out regarding the same ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your table `MANAGED` first:

```
ALTER TABLE abc SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE');
```

Then [truncate](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-TruncateTable):

```
truncate table abc;
```

And finally you can make it external again:

```
ALTER TABLE abc SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
```

Comment: @leftjoin- when we set 'EXTERNAL'='FALSE' for an external table, will it move the file location date to hive warehouse or it just help us to truncate the table.

Comment: @vikrantrana  truncate works only for managed tables, not external. Look at the docs: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-TruncateTable It says "Currently the target table should be native/managed table or an exception will be thrown. "

Comment: I think is much better Rahul's solution. Change the purge property to the external table. It works and it is clean.  ALTER TABLE mytable SET TBLPROPERTIES ('external.table.purge'='true'

Answer (score 3):

By default, TRUNCATE TABLE is supported only on managed tables. Attempting to truncate an external table results in the following error:

Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Operation not allowed: TRUNCATE TABLE on external tables

Action Required

Change applications. Do not attempt to run TRUNCATE TABLE on an external table.

Alternatively, change applications to alter a table property to set external.table.purge to true to allow truncation of an external table:

ALTER TABLE mytable SET TBLPROPERTIES ('external.table.purge'='true');

Answer (score 2):

There is an even better solution to this, which is basically a one liner.

```
insert overwrite table table_xyz select * from table_xyz where 1=2;
```

This code will delete all the files and create a blank file in the external folder location with absolute zero records.

Comment: Have you tried that with partitioned table?

Comment: Partitioned table will remain as is. This is misleading answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4367 : use

```
truncate table my_ext_table force;
```